# WCF MTOM message encoding with MessageContract

Tags: wcf, mtom

The requirement is to be able to upload a big file(~2GB) using a WCF service and I have created a messageContract class as follows

```
 [MessageContract]
public class TestMessageContract
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public byte[] UploadedFileContent { get; set; }        

}
```

and here is my web config on the service side

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpFileSize" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
       maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"
      messageEncoding="Mtom"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="1073741824" maxArrayLength="1073741824" maxBytesPerRead="1073741824"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfService1.IService1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpNormal" contract="WcfService1.IService1"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpFileSize" contract="WcfService1.IFileUploadService"/>
            <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:909/"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
```

The same binding configuration is used on the client side as well And here is the exception I am getting for the last 4 hours. I Couldn't figure the problem out..

Exception Content

Type multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="http://tempuri.org/0";boundary="uuid:382b5a40-f4f2-4399-9e63-b3f9e81227a5+id=2";start-info="application/soap+xml" was not supported by service http://localhost:909/Service1.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

Comment: maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" could be a problem if you are sending 2GB